# unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 784 bytes

Tags: python, machine-learning, struct, buffer, mnist

I'm running the following function for an ML model.

```
def get_images(filename):
    bin_file = open(filename, 'rb')
    buf = bin_file.read()  # all the file are put into memory
    bin_file.close()  # release the measure of operating system
    index = 0
    magic, num_images, num_rows, num_colums = struct.unpack_from(big_endian + four_bytes, buf, index)
    index += struct.calcsize(big_endian + four_bytes)
    images = []  # temp images as tuple
    for x in range(num_images):
        
        im = struct.unpack_from(big_endian + picture_bytes, buf, index)
        index += struct.calcsize(big_endian + picture_bytes)
        im = list(im)
        for i in range(len(im)):
            if im[i] > 1:
                im[i] = 1
```

However, I am receiving an error at the line:

```
im = struct.unpack_from(big_endian + picture_bytes, buf, index)
```

With the error:

```
error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 784 bytes
```

I have noticed this error is only occurring at certain iterations. I cannot figure out why this is might be the case. The dataset is a standard MNIST dataset which is freely available online.

I have also looked through similar questions on SO (e.g. [error: unpack_from requires a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799683/error-unpack-from-requires-a-buffer)) but they don't seem to resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you try to inspect the data in the except suite of a try/except? Looks like the data header is a fixed size and you expect each image to be a certain size: did you try to refactor to just read `struct.calcsize(big_endian + picture_bytes)` bytes and unpack that header then in a loop read successive `struct.calcsize(big_endian + picture_bytes)` bytes and unpack them?

Comment: What are you using for the formats: `big_endian`, `four_bytes`, and `picture_bytes`?? The header struct should be four unsigned longs - `">4L"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include the struct formats in your mre so it is hard to say why you are getting the error. Either you are using a partial/corrupted file or your struct formats are wrong.

This answer uses the test file `'t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz'` and file formats found at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/

Open the file and read it into a bytes object (gzip is used because of the file's type).

```
import gzip,struct
with gzip.open(r'my\path\t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz','rb') as f:
    data = bytes(f.read())
print(len(data))
```

The file format spec says the header is 16 bytes (four 32 bit ints) - separate it from the pixels with a slice then unpack it

```
hdr,pixels = data[:16],data[16:]
magic, num_images, num_rows, num_cols = struct.unpack(">4L",hdr)
# print(len(hdr),len(pixels))
# print(magic, num_images, num_rows, num_cols)
```

There are a number of ways to iterate over the individual images.

```
img_size = num_rows * num_cols
imgfmt = "B"*img_size
for i in range(num_images):
    start = i * img_size
    end = start + img_size
    img = pixels[start:end]
    img = struct.unpack(imgfmt,img)
    # do work on the img
```

Or...

```
imgfmt = "B"*img_size
for img in struct.iter_unpack(imgfmt, pixels):
    img = [p if p == 0 else 1 for p in img]
```

---

The [itertools grouper recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) would probably also work.